# Determine the particle velocity of a pressure wave

Tags: energy, waves, density, poynting-vector

I am using constant density wave propagators to model seismic waves in the subsurface. What I want with these acoustic waves is to estimate the energy of them at a certain grid point at a given time. One approach is using Poynting vectors based on the pressure distribution of the wave

$$ 
\vec{S} = \dot{p} \nabla p.
$$

The absolute value $|\vec{S}|$ resembles the energy of the wave.
Another way (and that's the problem) is based on the accoustic energy flux

$$ \vec{I} = p \vec{v},$$

where $\vec{v} = \frac{\vec{k}}{\rho \omega} = \frac{p}{\rho c} $ and $\rho$ is the density of the medium and $c$ is the medium velocity.

I want to compare $|\vec{I}|$ and $|\vec{S}|$ but stumble over the problem, that I do not specify $\rho$ in the wave modelling. As I want to compare both energies and use one of them as a threshold for the other, I can not simply assume $\rho$ to be a certain constant.

Is there another way to determine $\vec{v}$ without using the density?